# R: Dividing a time interval into shorter intervals

Tags: r, time, intervals, divide

I have a (Excel) sheet which assigns 5 second bursts a certain behaviour. So for one burst I have the start time, the end time and if the behaviour changed in between the time of this change and the new behaviour (see table). However, I would like to divide this 5 second bursts into 1 second burst taking into account the time of change.

```
Date        StartTime   EndTime   Behaviour   Change_to    Time_of_change  
17.06.2012  06:36:01    06:36:06  StHup       N            N
17.06.2012  06:36:06    06:36:11  StHup       StCl         06:36:08
17.06.2012  06:38:01    06:38:06  StHup       N            N
17.06.2012  06:38:06    06:38:11  StHup       N            N
```

I would like to convert the above table containing 4 rows into one with 20 rows, for example it should look like this for the second row (because the behaviour changes at 06:36:08):

```
Date        StartTime   EndTime   Behaviour
...
17.06.2012  06:36:06    06:36:07  StHup
17.06.2012  06:36:07    06:36:08  StHup
17.06.2012  06:36:08    06:36:09  StCl
17.06.2012  06:36:09    06:36:10  StCl
17.06.2012  06:36:10    06:36:11  StCl
...
```

I'm absolutly new to R and have now idea how to start, although I searched now the internet a long time. Could anyone please give me a hint how to start, which function I should have a look at?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Dr Neo The expected output is not clear especially `should show for 06:36:07 "StHup" but for 06:36:08-06:36:11 "StCl".`

Comment: rows 3 and 4 seem to have a negative time span.

Comment: I hope the new table helps and I changed the negative time span....

Comment: at then end of the day what you are doing is a "last value carried forward" - that is implemented by locf() in the zoo package. but the specifics of the implementations of going all the way from your data set to your destined data set are a bit beyond what I would like to invest in time for a question

Comment: Can the behavior change only once during the 5s period?

Comment: Yes it can only Change once because I eliminated already the data where it changed twice or more b